# How Spring loads properties file in memory?

Tags: java, spring

Am really new to spring, so please don't get angry and bear with me for a while.

I'm trying to understand how `application.properties` or any other external config file values gets associated with the places where config file's keys (`value="${log4j.configuration}"`) are mentioned to consume their values from file itself.

For example below is spring bean xml file:

```
<bean id = "propertiesToBeTaken"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:application.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:*keys.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="log4jLoader" class="my.loader.Log4jLoader">
        <property name="log4jCongif" value="${log4j.configuration}" />
</bean>
```

As you can see, `propertiesToBeTaken` is an instance of class `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

And in second case ,`log4jLoader` is an instance of class `my.loader.Log4jLoader`, where `log4j.configuration` key's value is assigned to Log4jLoader class's instance variable `log4jCongif`.

My questions are below:

1. There is no `locations` variable in class `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, then what is `locations` here and from where it came ? How can I relate `locations` to class's instance `propertiesToBeTaken`?
2. If lets say, `application.properties` key value pairs gets loaded into memory, then who or I mean which method loads that ? And even if it gets loaded then how those key value pairs of `application.properties` file are accessible to `Log4jLoader`'s instance variables...?
3. Last but I think it could very stupid question, In class `log4jLoader` class, there is a `setLog4jConfig(String log4jpropertiesLocation)`, but I really cant see who is calling this method. Just correct me here, Its not true, that In spring what ever the beans of object we have created, calls automatically class's instance methods. RIGHT ? I need to search more in code. CORRECT ?

Please put some light on my doubts here. Read about this alot on spring docs and online as well, but could not understand. Really want to understand how it's happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. `locations` in bean config XML is referring to the `setLocations` method of `PropertiesLoaderSupport` class which **Set locations of properties files to be loaded**. `PropertiesLoaderSupport` is parent class of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in multi-level inheritance. See [Official Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)
2. When `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` gets instantiated by Spring IoC, these properties are set in the bean, now any other bean in the config XML asks for property values using `${key.name}`, spring injects the value from the bean having value for this key. In your case `Log4jLoader` requires `${log4j.configuration}` so it's value will be injected by `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or it's any parent class.
3. `setLog4jConfig` spring calls this method when it has to give value to one of the property of the class `Log4jLoader`. In your case because of `<property name="log4jCongif" value="${log4j.configuration}" />` configuration spring will call setter method of the property `log4jCongif` to inject the value. **Yes** spring can call instance methods (specially setter) as per the configuration.

Comment: @Lenny does this clarifies you doubts?

Comment: Yes am getting the things now...! But tell me one thing How would you know that locations is  referring to the setLocations ? Secondly, Whenever we use spring framework, How and WHO manages that, spring related code or Configuration should be Instantiated first because their values are injected further in code to be used ...? I mean what's the flow and who manages this flow  ?  Spring is nothing but a Core java itself..!

Comment: Too many questions, for most questions, the answer is Spring's IoC Container does those things. If you think your doubts are clear on what you have asked then you can accept the answer so it can hep others too.